# Maintain PptxGenJS object across different views(pages)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `PptxGenJS.js` in my project which consists of graphs across various dashboards(pages/views),

I have a specific requirement where once the user adds a graph(`SVG image`) as a slide to the PptxGenJS object it should be maintained throughout the application till the user clicks on export ppt.

Please go through the below explanation for better understanding.

I initialise the `PptxGenJS` object in the `layout.cshtml` which is common for all the views.

```
var thispptx = new PptxGenJS();
```

And now in each view, there are multiple graphs, When the user clicks on `Add To PPT` button as shown below,

[image]

The slide gets added to the `PPT`

The `SVG` file gets added to the previously created `PptxGenJS` object.

i.e.

```
    $('#Chart1PPTId').click(function () 
{
  var pptslide1 = CreateSlide("#barChartz1", "bar",thispptx,CustomlabeltextForPPT);
});
function CreateSlide(divId, ChartType,pptx,SearchCriteria) {
        var slide = pptx.addNewSlide()
        var svg;
        if (ChartType != "guage") {
            svg = EntryPoint.getChartsvg(divId);
        }
        else {
            svg = EntryPoint.getGuageChartsvg(divId);
        }
        var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
        var svgBlob = new Blob([svg], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
        slide.addImage({ path: url, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, w: 9.0, h: 4.5});
        slide.addText('Search Criteria : ' + SearchCriteria, { x: 0.1, y: 5.2, font_size: 12, color: '363636' });
        return slide
    }
```

Now after adding several slides to the `PptxGenJS` object the user will click on `Export to PPT` button which will export it as a `PowerPoint` Presentation.

[image]

So my problem is that all of this works fine within the current page/view.

But my requirement is to maintain the same PptxGenJS object across all the views, which is not currently possible as I have initialised the PptxGenJS object in the layout which loads for every page/view (so a new PptxGenJS object is created for every view/page)

Is there a better way to handle this situation of mine?

Comment: no need to initialise object in layout you can do this in view page